# Displaying the arrival time and date to the user

Tags: python

How do I go about adding the time delta, so that I can add the delta value to the DateTime value and print it? For example, Estimated travel time Hours: 6 
Minutes: 15.0
Estimated date of arrival: 2018-11-30
Estimated time of arrival: 05:30 AM

But my program is just displaying this:
Estimated travel time
Hours:  3
Minutes:  4`

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
import locale

mph = 0
miles = 0
def get_departure_time():
    while True:
        date_str = input("Estimated time of departure (HH:MM AM/PM):  ")
        try:
            depart_time = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%H:%M %p")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again.")
            continue
        return depart_time


def get_departure_date():
    while True:
        date_str = input("Estimated date of departure (YYYY-MM-DD): ")
        try:
            depart_date = datetime.strptime(date_str, "%Y-%m-%d")
        except ValueError:
            print("Invalid date format. Try again. ")
            continue
        return depart_date

def distance():
    while True:
        miles = input("Enter miles to be travelled: ")
        try:
            miles = int(miles)
            if miles <= 0:
                print("Enter a Number Greater than 0.\n")
            else:
                return miles
        except ValueError:
            print("Format Error . Please Try again\n")
            continue

def speed():
    while True:
        speed = input("Enter miles per hour: ")
        try:
            mph = int(speed)
            if mph <= 0:
                print("Enter a Number Greater than 0.\n")
            else:
                return mph
        except ValueError:
            print("Format Error . Please Try again\n")
            continue
        pass

def travel_calculations(miles,mph):
    hours = int(miles/mph)
    minutes = int(((miles/mph)-hours)*60)
    time_travelled = timedelta(hours=hours, minutes=minutes)



    print("\n\nEstimated travel time")
    print("Hours: ", hours)
    print("Minutes: ", minutes)


def main():
    print("Arrival Time Estimator\n")
    depart_time = get_departure_time()
    depart_date = get_departure_date()

    miles = distance()
    mph = speed()
    travel_calculations(miles,mph)
    return


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()

`
```

Comment: You get `depart_date` and `depart_time` but don't use them for anything. Have you tried using them in conjunction with your `timedelta`?

Comment: I am new to python, could you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

Combine `depart_time` and `depart_date` to one `datetime` object in your `main()` function and supply it to `travel_calculations()`

```py
def main():
    ...
    departure = depart_date.replace(hour=depart_time.hour, minute=depart_time.minute)
    ...
    travel_calculations(miles, mph, departure)
```

Note, it would probably be a better idea to get both time and date at once and creating a single `datetime` object instead of having to add them together afterwards.

Then, in `travel_calculations()`, add your `timedelta` to the `datetime` object

```py
def travel_calculations(miles, mph, departure):
    ...
    eta = departure + time_travelled
```

You then have the estimated time of arrival available in the `eta` variable.